How to run a Python script on a SharePoint list in order to generate a PowerPoint file?
I currently have a local Python script that takes a CSV file (downloaded manually from SharePoint using the "Export as CSV" button) as input, processes the data, and generates a custom PowerPoint file using on a predefined template stored in the script's folder.
The process works fine locally, but I want to streamline it so users don't have to download the CSV file and script locally and manually. Instead, I'd like to:

Run the Python script directly on SharePoint.
Provide a simple button in SharePoint that users can click to trigger the script.
Have the script fetch the exported CSV file directly from SharePoint, process it, and then download the generated PowerPoint file

Any advice, best practices, or examples would be greatly appreciated, thanks

You can use The Microsoft Graph API to get all data from SharePoint list into your script.
Here, are some high-level steps for the same:

Use this package pip install msal requests in your script.

Register an Application in Azure:

Go to the Azure portal.
Register a new application to get the client_id, client_secret, and tenant_id.
Grant the application permissions for Sites.Read.All under Microsoft Graph API.


Authenticate and Retrieve Access Token:


Sample snippet:
import msal
import requests

client_id = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
client_secret = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
tenant_id = 'YOUR_TENANT_ID'
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    authority=authority
)

scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

if "access_token" in result:
    access_token = result["access_token"]
else:
    print("Error acquiring token:", result.get("error_description"))


Retrieve SharePoint List Data:

Sample Snippet:
site_id = 'YOUR_SITE_ID'
list_id = 'YOUR_LIST_ID'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
}

endpoint = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items?expand=fields"
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
data = response.json()

print(data)


Now, you have your data from the list. You can process further as per your business need.

This approach uses the Microsoft Graph API to authenticate and retrieve data from your SharePoint Online site.
Note: Above script may have some defects. I am not good in python scripts.

You can create SPFx Command Set Button on the SharePoint list view.
High-level steps:

Write your python script (as provided above) in Azure function.
Create SPFx Command Set button for your SharePoint list view.
Write logic in this Command Set button click event to call your Azure function as an HTTP trigger.

Once, your Azure function gets called, it will fetch SharePoint list data and you can further create your PowerPoint file using this data.
